# Vim not pasting full code

Tags: vim, paste

I'm trying to paste from Google Chrome into my terminal running vim but for some reason the code gets cut off.

For example I'll copy:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

But then it will come out as:

```
g/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How are you pasting the text in? Looks like you're using <CTRL>-v (or equivalent) in normal mode, which simply sends all characters to vim. This means that up until you get to a character that enters insert mode nothing actually gets pasted in. Either go into insert mode first (and you probably want to `:set paste` first), or use either `"+p` or `"*p` (depending on the clipboard used to copy the text) in normal mode.

Comment: [Automatically set paste mode in Vim when pasting in insert mode](https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode)

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you have to enter insert mode first when using system-wide shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> for pasting.

Otherwise Vim interprets everything you paste as commands. This is why it start pasting after `{% extends 'blo` - `o` is a command which enters insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

To paste copied text in verbatim, enable `:set paste` and be in insert mode and paste it.

You may like to set `pastetoggle` to a key also. `:help pastetoggle`.

As being in paste mode is not preferred due to its repercussions, set paste mode only when required.